# add in object in array after submit

Tags: reactjs, object, state

I am facing a problem. If you can give me some advice, it would be a huge help for me.

I have a state with object

```js
const [work , setWork] = useState({company:"" , jobTitle:"", jobType:"", location:""});

const [list, setList] = useState([]);
```

I want when the user update and submit the state, I send the object in an array list [ ]

companyValue is is the result of onChange

```js
const add = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
    
            if(companyValue){
                setWork(prevState => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    company: companyValue
                }))
                 setList(prevState => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    work
                 }))
                    }
               }
```

and I want to have a result like this

```js
list = [
        {company:"" , jobTitle:"", jobType:"", location:""},
        {company:"" , jobTitle:"", jobType:"", location:""},
        {company:"" , jobTitle:"", jobType:"", location:""}
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
const newWork = {
  ...work,
  company: companyValue
}

setWork(newWork);

setList(
  list.concat(newWork)
)
```

If you want to add only that `companyValue`, which I assume look like this: `{company:"" , jobTitle:"", jobType:"", location:""}`, then you can do this:

```
setList(
  list.concat(companyValue)
);
```

Comment: thank's  it works, but the value it added after 2 submit, do you have any idea about that

Comment: Which solution you used? the work one or the companyValue one?

Comment: the first one with list.concat(work)

Comment: Okay, try the second one and lemme know.

Or you can try this: 

`
const newWork = {
  ...work,
  company: companyValue
}

setWork(newWork);

setList(
  list.concat(newWork)
)
`

Comment: I'll edit my answer :D

Comment: i have the result, thank you so much Anas, you saved my day

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247791/discussion-between-anas-latique-and-moufid-sgh).